Error con librería libswiftAVFoundation.dylib - IOS 17.4 - Genexus 18 U8
Al momento de actualizar la version de nuestra app que ya se encuentra en produccion, desde apple no nos la aceptan por lo siguiente:
"termination" : {"code":1,"flags":518,"namespace":"DYLD","indicator":"Library missing","details":["(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"],"reasons":["L**ibrary not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib" **....
No realizamos ningun cambio de version en la mac, ni en genexus entre esta version y la version anteriormente validada por apple.
MacOs Sonoma 14.0 Genexus 18U8 Xcode 15.0
